# module file saver not found in angular

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I have installed the saver file using

```
npm install @ types/file-saver --save-dev
```

Why can't I find the module?

and show this in my project:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file-saver' in 'D:\myAngular\src\app\admin\product'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have only installed **@types/file-saver** which is just the type definitions for the actual **file-saver** package and need to install the latter independently.

> npm i file-saver

See this [link](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/308#issuecomment-279739618) for a simple example if you're still getting errors.